# What is Return Scalar in Hibernate and How to use this

Tags: java, hibernate

Kindly explain the Return Scalar concept in Hibernate

Regards
Manish Srivastava

Comment: It means that you have a query that returns a simple, single value (for example an integer) instead of a complete entity (an object).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please review the following, it will help you going forward. [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 4):

The "Return Scalar" concept is used to return particular column of hibernate entity.

we are using this concept with Named Query

In above query we are going to fetch only Customer fname and lname

The "Return Scalar" returns List of Object array of size (number of field that you want to return)
in this example it will return List of Object array of size 2
you can access arr[0](for fname) and arr[1](for lname)